# Getting shared folders to work on a VM

Tags: windows, virtualization, vmware, shared-folders, vmware-workstation

- VMWare Workstation Pro Version 17.0.2 build-21581411
- Host System: Win 10 Pro most recent version
- Guest OS: Zorin OS 16 Core most recent version

I want to setup a shared folder between my windows host and my zorinOS(Ubuntu) guest that runs as a VM. In workstation I enabled "Shared Folders" and configured a folder with my host system. The guest has the most recent version of open-vm-tools-desktop installed and is in general everything is up to date.
Following the [docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-AB5C80FE-9B8A-4899-8186-3DB8201B1758.html) I run the following on the guest machine
`/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /home/user1/shares -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other`
and get faced with `/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse: File or folder not found`
If I run `vmhgfs-fuse` I'm getting the info that the command `vmhgfs-fuse` could not be found but can be installed with `sudo apt install open-vm-tools` .
Despite the fact that I already got it installed, I now run `sudo apt install open-vm-tools`
and ofcourse get the info that nothing happened because I already got the most recent version of open-vm-tools installed. Send help.